# Spark - concatenate strings of each partition to a single string

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD which contains the lines of a file. I want for each partition NOT to contain the lines, but the concatenated lines. For example:

```
Partition 1        Partition 2
  line 1            line n/2+1
  line 2            line n/2+2
    .                  .
    .                  .
    .                  .
  line n/2          line n
```

Figure1 above shows my RDD, which is produced when we use sc.textFile() method. I want to go from figure 1 above to the one below (figure 2):

```
        Partition 1                        Partition 2
concatenatedLinesFrom1toN/2        concatenatedLinesFromN/2+1toN
```

Is there any way to map the partitions so I can convert the RDD from figure 1 to the one in Figure 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you you need uniform object size (in-memory size / number of characters):

```
rdd.glom.map(_.mkString)
```

If you want a relativelly uniform number of lines not uniform size:

```
import org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner

val indexed = rdd.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)
indexed.partitionBy(new RangePartitioner(2, indexed))
  .values
  .glom
  .map(_.mkString)
```

where `rdd` is a `RDD[String]` returned from `textFile` or similar method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rdd.mapPartitions(itr)` to achieve this.
EDIT
`res0.mapPartitions(x=>Seq(x.mkString("")).iterator).collect`

Comment: Perhaps elaborate a bit more on how this can help the OP. Simply saying "use this method" is usually not so helpful.